# Places SDK for iOS (coded in Flutter)

Tags: ios, flutter, sdk

We have Rideshare app being developed using Places SDK for iOS (coded in Flutter).  When device is connected to WIFI and I start to type in address (ex. 23...) address options within my location (city/state) display.  When not connected to WIFI and scheduling a new ride request, I enter 23 to get close addresses and instead got addresses in Denmark, Netherlands, London, Mexico and Australia.  How can we fix??